# Rhymes in William Blake's 'The Tyger'

Tags: poetry, william-blake, songs-of-experience

> Tyger Tyger, burning bright,
> In the forests of the night;
> What immortal hand or eye,
> Could frame thy fearful symmetry?

'Eye' and 'symmetry' don't rhyme in modern standard English. But pronunciation can shift over 200+ years. How would those two words have been spoken by Blake himself?

'Eye is sometimes pronounced as 'ee' in Scottish dialect, which would be a proper rhyme. Would Blake have said it that way?

Comment: The same question has been asked on the English Language site here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216345/was-the-pronunciation-of-symmetry-different-in-the-past

Answer (score 5):

No!

Here is an example that proves how Blake pronounces "eyes", from [*Songs of Innocence*](https://blake.lib.asu.edu/html/songs_of_innocence_and_of_experience.html#sititle):

> Sweet moans, dovelike **sighs**,
> Chase not slumber from thy **eyes**.
> Sweet moans, sweeter smiles,
> All the dovelike moans beguiles.

---

Personally, I think Blake
rhymes "eye" on line three [internally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rhyme) with "thy" on line four.
While certainly a weak form of internal rhyme, "thy" satisfies our expectation of a rhyme, breaks the purposeful childish singsong rhyme and meter up to this point, placing a mid line emphasis on "thy", leaving space for that [sublime](https://poemanalysis.com/william-blake/the-tyger/) "fearful symmetry".

Changing meter my way to reveal the effect:

> Tyger Tyger
> burning bright,
> In the forests
> of the night:
> What immortal
> hand or eye,
> Dare frame thy
> fearful symmetry?

Comment: I am being *Mr Twit*! The very next line 5 and 6 of *The Tyger* prove the point: "In what distant deeps or skies. / 
Burnt the fire of thine eyes?"